How to Predict a Growing Time Series with Changing Slopes in Python?
I have a univariate time series dataset that represents a continuously growing trend, but the slope changes at different intervals. I want to predict future values of this time series.
Here are some key details:
The series is always increasing.
The slope changes at various points.
The data has only one variable.
I am looking for suitable models or methods to accurately predict future values.
I need to perform forecasting beyond the test set, meaning using predictions to predict further into the future iteratively.
So far, I have considered linear regression, but it doesn't handle the changing slopes well. I have also looked into ARIMA, but I'm not sure how to configure it for this scenario.
Can anyone recommend appropriate models or techniques in Python to handle this type of time series? Examples or references to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Linear regression means the coefficients show up linearly, not the function type itself. You can use linear regression to fit polynomials, exponentials, logarithms, power functions, all sorts of things.

First off, look at first differences. If your time series is indeed growing at piecewise constant slopes, taking first differences will transform this into a piecewise constant time series. Since all your slopes are positive, the first differences will all be positive.
If you can forecast the first differences, then the backtransformation is simply one of taking cumulative sums.
Now you have a simpler problem. You need to forecast when the differenced time series will have a step, and what the new step will be.
To do this, you need to take domain knowledge into account. Is there some external factor driving the changes that you could leverage? Is there some kind of regularity or periodicity? Even probabilistic predictions of the timing and height of the steps may be helpful, because then you can at least simulate the future. Alternatively, sometimes it is more useful to control a system, rather than try to forecast it.
Of course, any errors in forecasting the first differences will translate into larger errors when you backtransform. But that is just a consequence of your problem.

sometimes it is more useful to control a system, rather than try to forecast it. That is insightful, thank you!

@Galen: more often, the non-forecasters in a system work as if they were actively trying to make the system less forecastable. In retail forecasting, that would be the marketing department that creatively dreams up new promotions... which are of course much harder to forecast and therefore much harder on the supply chain than promotions we have seen for years and that we have learned from. So that line of mine was more aspirational than practical.

I see your point with the marketing example, but it is practical to me! You've got me pulling out my old control theory notes. There are some systems that may be more controllable than forecast-able. Disruptions cannot always be predicted, but in some systems they can responded to as needed. It is food for thought.
